# How can I change which file manager dropbox opens with by default?

Tags: xfce, thunar, dropbox

I installed Xubuntu on a new laptop I got, and this being my first time using xfce, I accidentally told my dropbox folder to open with nautilus (coming from ubuntu) and not thunar. Now it will not allow me to open the folder via the task bar. Is there any way to tell it to use thunar instead?

Answer (score 6):

Dropbox is integrated with Nautilus, however, there is a hack from the Crunchbang Wiki that [works around this](http://crunchbanglinux.org/wiki/howto/howto_setup_dropbox). Create a script, `/bin/nautilus`:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec thunar ~/Dropbox
exit 0
```

so that dropbox's requests for a file manager are passed to Thunar.

There is also a plugin, [Thunar Dropbox](http://softwarebakery.com/maato/thunar-dropbox.html) that provides the context menus for dropbox in Thunar (Copy Public Link etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to allow the script to accept the binaries requested location to open. Move `/usr/bin/nautilus` aside and create a new script as  `/usr/bin/nautilus` and add the following;

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/caja $@
```

This will allow the script to open a path given after the command.  Note that this script replaces the nautilus binary, so if ever needed move your script aside and move back the original binary nautilus to re-enable the original nautilus.